# Using WinForms with XNA?

Tags: c#, winforms, xna, xna-4.0

Can you use WinForms with XNA? I would like to use the drag and drop of the WinForms, *and use* XNA for animations and stuff.

I am wasting a lot of time coding the buttons (in XNA), so with this I thought it would speed my time up.

Comment: That is one seriously misleading question title.

Comment: [App Hub - Winforms](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to create hybrid between Xna and Winform. Check out this project http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1

Answer (score 0):

Why not use WPF?! It has the same 'function' as WinForms and has the ability to implement animations in a simple way (much more simple than in WinForms anyway).